# Is it possible to have a custom mix file for Elixir?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

In my projects involving Elixir, I often have stuff I want to add to my `mix.exs` file for example adding my own `ENV` etc. It's usually a pain to add these items and have to add them to my `.gitignore`. My question is, is it possible to have something like `custom_mix.exs` which I can call from `mix` where I can put in all of my custom settings which will overwrite the settings that are defined in `mix.exs` ? The `custom_mix.exs` file will not be put under git and can be permanently put under `.gitignore` and `mix.exs` will not error out if no `custom_mix.exs` is found.

Answer (score 4):

While the answer by Steve Pallen is perfectly correct, you are doing it wrong in the first place. This definitely looks like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Why would you put *settings* in `mix.exs` file, while you have `config/config.exs` for this particular purpose? `config.exs` has a built-in support for what your’re looking for out of the box, check how e.g. [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework) does different configurations for different environments.

`mix.exs` file is intended to specify the general application behaviour and what you are currently trying to achieve is to make the application behaviour *undetermined*.

---

The possible problem you could try to resolve this way, that I could think of, is versioning of dependent applications or doing some patchwork on external `mix.exs` code. Still, the approach to tackle and fight against the core elixir project file is a bad idea. You might create a wrapper for the original `mix.exs` file, calling it’s functions from your version and forcing Elixir to use your version with some shell wrappers, or like.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve a seperate set of requirements say something like dependencies for projects but I want to only have them for my own config say `:lowks` -> `{:bypass, "~> 0.6", only: [:lowks, :test, :wercker]}` ?

Comment: Everything is possible. Now I am sure this is an X/Y problem. If the dependency is _a dependency_, you can’t throw it out for your users. If it’s yours, private etc, then yes (`only: ` option is there to specify _environments_.) You are welcome, do the above and run `MIX_ENV=lowks iex -S mix`.

Comment: agree with @mudasobwa I still don't understand why you would want to do this. The only thing I ever do in mix.exs if toggle a dependency between local path and hex/github when I'm working on the dependency. Then I just comment on the two deps lines and remove the local path version when I release.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, very easy to do. Add the following to the very top of your mix.exs file

```
if File.exists?("./custom_mix.exs"), do: Code.require_file("./custom_mix.exs", __DIR__)

defmodule MyApp.Mixfile do
  # ...
  if function_exported?(CustomMix, :some_stuff, 0), 
    do: CustomMix.some_stuff()
end
```

Then create your custom_mix.exs file like this:

```
defmodule CustomMix do
  def some_stuff do
    #
  end
end
```

Comment: This will not cause `mix` to bomb out if `custom_mix.exs` is not found right ?